# retrain a previously trained model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API. I started training a model for a couple of hours and I want to add more images to the dataset and start training again from epoch 1. What would be the best way to do this? I know that if a run now python train.py is it going to continue from the last checkpoint, something that I don't want because I want to retrain over again and with more data. I am thinking to delete the files in the training folder which is where checkpoints and other files related are. I just not sure about what files to delete from that folder or if that is the proper way.

**UPDATE:** Indeed, I just need to delete all the files (checkpoints) from the training directory and run again python train.py. That would start the training from the step 1

Comment: You can saved the trained model and load it on the next run w/o loosing the training. Also can you provide link to which api you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bhupen. I think my question was not clear. All that I want is to train again my model with more data and from the first step. I was training before but now I want to increase accuracy adding more pictures to my dataset which is trained in only one class. The issue is that if a run python train.py is it going to continue from the last checkpoint.